# SOAP request with cyrillic characters in parameters

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

There is a web-service with WSDL interface, and I have to make a simple client for this service. I've got WSDL files parsed and made a client logic based on them. That logic have to take key value from the client, make a SOAP request with this value, sent that request to server, get the response a show a value from response. The service is able to take key values from client written in both English and Russian, and request in English works fine. But when I try to sent request with cyrillic symbols, server returns a wrong result. I think it's because of encoding. I've tried to convert that string into `UTF-8` with this code (Java)

```
String city = "Москва";
byte[] pt;
pt = city.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
city = new String(pt, "UTF-8");
```

I know `String` in Java can only store an `UTF-16` value, so this is probably useless, but the method from service's WSDL I should use can take only `String`. SOAP request have `utf-8` in its parameters, too. What should I do to make a web-service take a cyrillic symbols in correct encoding? Can I change WSDL classes parsed from WS to make them generate request with `utf-16` encoding or it's a wrong idea?

Comment: Why don't you just: pt = city.getBytes("UTF-8");

Comment: I've tried that, but nothing changed anyway.